# How to add URL to vCard 2.1?

Tags: vcf-vcard

I am trying to add the website URL to business card.I have created the vCard string and the business card is generating with image. All that is left is the website URL.

The string I am generating is :

```
$vcard = 'BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:'.$attendee['name'].'
FN:'.$attendee['name'].'
ORG:'.$attendee['organization'].'
TITLE:'.$attendee['title'].'
TEL;WORK;VOICE:'.$attendee['phone'].'
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:'.$attendee['email'].'
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPG:'.$image.'
REV:20080424T195243Z


END:VCARD';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
URL;type=pref:http\://www.example.com
```

Comment: the solution is not working when opening the vCard in Microsoft Outlook Express

Comment: I think you can try to eliminate the "type=pref" part. Or change the type to website.

Comment: it seems that your solution was right. i found out that if you add the URL after the base64 encoded string of the image, the URL will not appear.